# Como Executar um metodo na finalização da seção?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Preciso executar determinado metodo quando a seção for encerrada (quando o usuário clicar em fechar o browser). Estou trabalhando com JSP e não sei como posso fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar algumas coisas utilizando Javascript e/ou Jquery:

Primeiro modo:

Você pode utilizar o unload do Jquery: http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Segundo modo:

Utilizar um bind com javascript:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
 alert("fechei");
```

});

Adicional:

Experimentar as seguintes funções:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){alert("oi");}
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){alert("oi");}, false);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Att